# How to setCenter using Just co-ordinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi I've tried this a couple of ways and I'm not sure what I'm missing. The documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference states that I should be able to set the center of my Map using the coordinates like this:

setCenter(latlng:LatLng)

which I am guessing means I can use the syntax:

```
myMap.setCenter(-37.8025182,144.9987055);
```

but I get the error "Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property : -37.8025182 "

Is there something I'm missing - the documentation doesn't really give me any clues.

Regards,

Lea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says the *single* argument for `setCenter` is a `LatLng`. `setCenter` doesn't take two Numbers.

```
var centerpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8025182,144.9987055);
myMap.setCenter(centerpoint);
```

or combine everything together:

```
myMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8025182,144.9987055));
```

Comment: I get it - so I have to create the LatLng class and then pass it to setCenter. I've written a function as I'll be doing this a lot:
`code`function setCentrebyLatLng ( aLat, aLng) {
 var centrepoint = new google.maps.LatLng(aLat,aLng);
  tramMap.setCenter(centrepoint);
} `code` 
Thanks - I'm a bit of a Javascript newbie.